# If $a_n \to \infty$ and $b_n \to \infty$ and $\exists n_0, \forall n > n_0: a_n < b_n$, then $a_n/b_n \to 0$

Tags: limits

I need to prove that
$\log(n)/n\to 0$. Surely $\exists n_0, \forall n > n_0 \log(n) < n$. I want to give a general proof. That is:
for any sequence $a_n \to \infty$ and $b_n \to \infty, \exists n_0, \forall n > n_0: a_n < b_n \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n/b_n = 0$.
Is it actually true? How can I prove it?

Comment: Hint for the limit you need to prove: $$0 \le \frac{\log n}{n} = \frac{2 \log \sqrt n}{\sqrt n \sqrt n} \le \frac{2}{\sqrt n} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider as a counterexample

$$a_n=n-1 \quad b_n=n$$

To prove the given limit by $x=e^y$ we have

$$\frac{\log x}{x}=\frac{y}{e^y} \to 0 \implies \frac{\log n}{n}\to 0$$

Comment: You are welcome $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

It is false : take $a_n = n$ and $b_n = 2n$